# Add on click event to p elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, onclick

I am trying to add an onclick event to each of the p elements created.
I need to do this within the for loop so that the rest of the info in the 'data' array relates to the clicked result.

It is an autocomplete search function that looks up a contact and displays the Name and Company Name in a dropdown.
When you click on it, it will fill in the corresponding fields with the other information like an email address and phone number.

How would I go about adding an onclick event to each p element within the for loop?

```js
//Instant Search for Key Contact lookups
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_customer').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var term = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $("#result");
        var i = 0;
        var results = '';
        if(term.length){
            $.get("/profile/includes/custom/340/livesearch.php", {query: term}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                results += '<p>' + data[i][0] + ' ' + data[i][1] + ' | <span>' + data[i][2] + '</span></p>';
              }
              resultDropdown.html(results);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
});
```

I would want the function of each onclick to be something like this:

```js
p.on("click", function(){
        $("#search_customer").val(data[i][0] + ' ' + data[i][1]);
        $("#customer_email").val(data[i][[5]);
        $("#customer_company").val(data[i][6]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your p element and then make an event handler for the click of that class.

So on this line:

```
results += '<p>' + data[i][0] + ' ' + data[i][1] + ' | <span>' + data[i][2] + '</span></p>';
```

Add a class:

```
results += '<p class="placeholderClassname">' + data[i][0] + ' ' + data[i][1] + ' | <span>' + data[i][2] + '</span></p>';
```

And then your Jquery handler:

```
$( ".placeholderClassname" ).on( "click", function() {
  //Write code here
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

You could also have your Jquery handler on all p elements but that can create problems if you have other p elements in your page.

More information on the Jquery event handler: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I would still need a way to retain the 'i' variable or else it won't keep the array of results matching the displayed name with the rest of the data(email, phone, etc..)

Comment: In the click event. $(this) contains the p element clicked. So you can use that and get whatever information you need on the clicked p. Please refer to the JQuery documentation to learn about selectors.